# Javascript convert foreach to for loop in modulo

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, modulo

Noob question here. I am trying to convert this forEach to a For loop but for some reason, this is returning undefined:

This is the forEach:

[image]

This is the for Loop that keeps displaying undefined:

[image]

Feel like such a nob for asking this but

Comment: Hey, if possible please post your actual code in your question as opposed to image(s) of your code. It helps everyone.

Comment: You want `number[i] % 3` in your `for` loop. Alternatively, use a `for..of` loop, ie `for (let num of number) { ... }`

Comment: @segFault I am still navigating through Stackoverflow. This was my first time asking a question and there was an error that was generating based on the format of the question but point taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `if` condition, you are having condition `number % 3` instead of `number[i] % 3`
Correct code:

```js
var number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

for(var i=0; i<number.length;i++){
    if(number[i]%3 == 0){
        alert(number[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change  the condition in your if statement from `number%3==0`  to `number[i]%3==0`. Currently, you are checking if the whole list (number) is divisible by 3 or not.
By changing, the condition you check if the particular iteration's index is divisible by 3 or not, also change `i=1` to `i=0` , this wail start your loop from  the first index.